# how to pass column names including space in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

assume my column names are: User ID and name 
how should I pass this column name to functions like what I have below?

```
df %>%
  group_by(User ID) %>%
  count(name)
```

apparently, group_by() or similar functions do not accept column names with space in their names.

Comment: You can try backticks delimiting the name with spaces.

Comment: @PaulS, do you mean ` ? I tried this but it is working.

Comment: Yes, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `tibble` instead of `data.frame`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(`User ID` = 1:2, x = 5:6)
  
df %>%
  group_by(`User ID`) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(x))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   `User ID` total
#>       <int> <int>
#> 1         1     5
#> 2         2     6
```